# Convert String to Date Object in Java, Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, date, date-parsing

I need to parse strings from the following type in Date objects in Java.
"2021-05-19T20:43:29+00:00".
I tried parsing it to "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX" and "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ" but both didn't work. I cannot find the specific format for this type.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you really *have* to use `Date`?

Answer (score 1):

I found that what works for me is the following

```
String dateFromAPI = "2021-05-19T20:43:29+00:00";
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( dateFromAPI );
Instant instant = odt.toInstant();
Date date = Date.from(instant);
```

Comment: Good Answer, except for that last line of code. `java.util.Date` class is *terrible*, flawed in both design and implementation. Sun, Oracle, and the JCP community all gave up on that class years ago with the unanimous adoption of JSR 310. I suggest you do the same.